# Sonarqube squid:S2699 if jsonPath validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have implemented controller test (using spring web testing framework).

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/calendar").contentType(V1_0)
            .content(toJSON(createCalendarDto(expectedCalendar))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(V1_0))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(notNullValue())))
            //...
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is(expectedCalendar.getEmail())));
```

this test covers some important cases, checking json structure and field values.

Test works correctly, sonar prints a message:

*Tests should include assertions. Code smell Critical squid:S2699*

I could use workaround like `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2699")` but I hope it can be managed in better way.

---

java 1.8
Sonarcube Version 6.3.1
Spring-boot 1.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've found a false positive in a rule. Specifically, your test framework is not taken into account by the rule.

The best course for rule false positives in general is to open a thread on the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) saying, essentially, "For language L, could you add case X to rule Y, please?". Don't forget to include a minimum code sample to reproduce the false positive.

**Update** It's a Discourse instance now: https://community.sonarsource.com/

Comment: Good point, it's useful to know. I hope to get answer from Spring developers, I believe they have solved this situation and I could use their solution (in `dev` or `test` tools). I hope i've used testing part of framework incompletely or incorrectly.